# Remote wipe iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, icloud

Trying to develop a BYOD service for my enterprise. I am new to iOS and starting with some basic services like remote wipe from a web console.
How should I approach this problem?
What are tutorials/blog posts on this topic?
I found that services like remote wipe and find my phone are available on iCloud. Should I use iCloud API on my web control panel to do it?

Comment: This isn't really the sort of question for Stack Overflow. Also, are you saying that you would encourage people to use their own devices, which you would get the power to remotely wipe? Not really seeing the incentive for the employee!

Comment: If user have registered their phone with the service and wants to wipe it when it's lost.

Comment: They can do that themselves anyway, using iCloud. Anyway I'm pretty sure (and I hope) it's impossible; Apple keeps remote wiping to themselves, and has no API for it. I hope that's the case because otherwise any developer could wipe a device which their app is installed on at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your enterprise uses Microsoft Exchange you can setup policies to control remote wiping through exchange.  The policy options are pretty powerful.  You can give the user access to wipe their own device through the webmail portal or exchange admin's can wipe a device...